# Authenticate with Active Directory but use SQL membership provider for the rest?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, authentication, active-directory, asp.net-4.5

I have a legacy, monster software that is built around SQL membership. It isn't the most elegant code and sometimes the code goes directly into the database to pull users or roles out.

I need to migrate this to Active Directory. I'm thinking of authenticating against Active Directory, then saving the user on-demand into SQL. That way, the rest of the code works when trying to work with users, roles, etc against SQL. I would also have to plug the places where users are created and deleted.

Is it possible to authenticate against Active Directory via form authentication, but use SQL membership for the rest?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure what you ask is possible, but you may want to consider authenticating against [ADFS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb897402.aspx) instead of directly against Active Directory.

ADFS issues security tokens you can use to make authorization decisions. You can have it issue role claims into the token based on look-ups in a SQL attribute store. If your application is using things like [`IPrincipal.IsInRole`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.isinrole(v=vs.110).aspx) to determine permissions, it should not have to change much.

Moving your application to token based authentication will make it easier to make your application internet ready ([ADFS proxy](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2012/01/05/understanding-the-ad-fs-2-0-proxy.aspx)) or trust issuers from other authentication domains ([federation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_identity)).